# Why is $ defined in my browser if I didn't load jquery

Tags: jquery, browser

For some reason jquery is automatically being loaded in my browser as if it was native to the browser. $ is supposed to be undefined if jquery is not being loaded. Even if I open a new tab and type $ in the console, it is allowing me to use jquery. How is this happening?

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate. The solution is to always check for `jQuery`, not `$`, to determine if jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: jQuery is undefined. My question is why is $ defined...

Comment: Yep, that's what the duplicate and my previous comment addresses.